# Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule using a variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, sccm

I have a power shell command line where i am trying to import a txt file filled with serial numbers (example. "123","456", etc.) into SCCM to create a device collection. I am trying to import within parameters so it only create 1 Query using List of Values, but I keep getting an error "A Positional paramter cannot be found that accepts argument .\process.txt"

```
$Process = ".\process.txt

Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule -Collection $collection -RuleName "Membership $collectionName" -QueryExpression "select * from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT.IdentifyingNumber in "`("$Process"`)""
```

Expected Results

select * from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM_PRODUCT.IdentifyingNumber in ("9876","6543",12345")

Actual Results

```
Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Process.txt)'.
At C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Add2Sccm_Works SerialNumber - Copy.ps1:42 char:1
+ Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule -Collection $collection -Ru ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-CMDeviceCol...yMembershipRule], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Collections.Comman
   ds.AddDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRuleCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

$Process is being specified as .\Process.txt, which looks like it expands to '(C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Process.txt)'.  This is what you are passing to your membership query rule.

Try changing to

```
$process = Get-Content ".\Process.txt"
```

This will read the items in the file and pass that to the query

Comment: Thank you, I feel like i'm getting closer, But now I am receiving this error

Comment: Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"5CG4444","5CG1111"'.
At C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Add2Sccm_Works SerialNumber - Copy.ps1:43 char:1
+ Add-CMDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRule -Collection $collection -Ru ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-CMDeviceCol...yMembershipRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.Cmdlets.Collections.Comman
   ds.AddDeviceCollectionQueryMembershipRuleCommand

Comment: What does your process.txt look like?  Can you show the first few lines?

Comment: yea, the txt file looks like this "5CG4444","5CG1111","5CG3333" and so on

Comment: Does the error change if you specify  "`($Process`)"` without the double quotes instead of "`("$Process"`)"